# Wrong Beneficiary name in swift transactions.Wire transfer

Tags: transfer, swift

I have made a transfer to the company via wire transfer, swift remittance. But unfortunately, I have given the wrong beneficiary name, but all other IFSC codes, swift codes are correct. The company claim that they didn't receive the payment. What I have to do now?

Comment: Can you state which country from and to?

Comment: you would have given account number right ? was the account number correct ?

Comment: @Fattie It is from Bank Of America to HDFC bank india

Comment: @VenkataramanR Yes sir, the account number, IFSC codes, Swift code everything is correct.

Comment: oh no .. HDFC and most India banks will delay and delay.  You could be in for a long wait until it is sorted out   :O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a complete nightmare.

1. The best and only thing you can do is **contact your bank** and hope for the best.
2. Do note that it can **take some days**, so it may just have not hit yet.
3. NORMALLY - not always but NORMALLY, let us say 70% of the time - if the name or perhaps address is slightly wrong, it should still work OK. The name is "not really used" in most permutations of from/to countries/banks.
4. If the name was COMPLETELY wrong you may have trouble. If a slight difference, less trouble.

If you like, say the name of the sending bank.

The desks of most banks that handle this are absolutely useless, so, expect a lot of trouble. You have to press and press and press - normally they will just put you off.

---

> "XYZ Educational Trust", I have mentioned "XYZ University"

Normally that should be not a big deal.  However ...

> Going to India ...

You face trouble. They will delay and delay.  My guess is it will eventually go through but only after VAST effort on your side.

> Which Side of the branch, I have to raise the query

Unfortunately you can only deal with "your" bank.  If you call the receiving bank in India, almost certainly they will just not talk to you :/

Comment: Thank you. Actually instead of "XYZ Educational Trust", I have mentioned "XYZ University". Still, I didn't get any response. Which Side of the branch, I have to raise the query, sir? Beneficiary's bank or Remiter's Bank??

Comment: I try my best to contact the bank.  Thank y

Comment: any chances do I lose my money?? That's my fear.

Comment: I hate to tell you that there is some small chance you may lose your money.  You must contact your bank vigorously.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are fine, as you have given the correct account number. Account number is the primary one used for depositing money. You can again check whether money got deposited.

Also, in case it has gone to wrong account, below is the addressal process:

[Economic times Source](https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/industry/banking/finance/banking/why-getting-the-account-number-right-is-very-necessary-while-transferring-funds-online/articleshow/46820157.cms?from=mdr)

[image: Redressal process]

Comment: I think fortunately it's probably **unlikely** it has gone to **another** account.  (Fortunately.)

Comment: @Fattie, 100% agree with you. Fortunately, he has given right account number.

Comment: @VenkataramanR, thank you all. Hope things will go well.

Comment: I love the phrase "The beneficiary is intimidated..." in the graphic instead of the more common phrase "The beneficiary isi intimated..." which is Indglish for "The beneficiary is informed..."